# Why does PCRE static library differs in size on Win and Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, static-libraries, pcre

It's the first time I've used PCRE library in my project. I downloaded the source code (version 8.20) and built it with the same options on linux and windows (both x86). I am really puzzled with the difference in the librarys' sizes. On windows I have a static lib of 138Kb while on Linux it is 1700Kb whcih is more than 12 times as much.
I will appreciate any comments on this. Maybe I was doing something wrong?

UPDATE:
Configure options are: --disable-cpp --enable-utf8 --enable-newline-is-any
Optimization flag is -O2
On win built with mingw gcc version 4.5.2
On linux built with gcc version 4.3.2

Comment: "built it with the same options on linux and windows" - would you care to list those options, so people could perhaps reproduce the effect on their own machines? Also, probably worth listing compilers used with versions.

Comment: It would also help to know what dynamic libraries each version is linked against.

Comment: Those static libraries aren't linked against any dynamic libraries. Each static lib doesn't depend on anything else.

Comment: Perhaps the linux library includes debugging information.

Comment: Well, I tied to find any debugging options in pcre, but I haven't found anything. Maybe there are some debugging gcc flags on Linux which are used by default and I am not aware of them???

Answer (score 1):

Since you're targeting the native platform, MingW is using its Windows CRL for the Windows library, and the Linux one for...that.

The MingW documentation says that it uses the "CRL that comes with Windows," which is a DLL that thinly abstracts the Win32 API. So the library you're compiling with MingW would then be loading a DLL, meaning that significant code is in a separate file (the .DLL) whereas the Linux one most likely statically links the GCC CRL that is appropriate to the platform.

On Linux, the statically linked library uses the statically linked CRL that is appropriate. This means more-or-less including a large portion of the CRL, because you may call the library later with something that uses a different CRL, it aids in whole-program optimization, etc.

Down the pipeline, like when you compile an actual executable in Linux, you will probably find that the most of the static library isn't included in the final executable, so this size difference should be much smaller between executables (though the static-only Linux one will probably be bigger still, other factors notwithstanding).

There are many advantages/disadvantages to each approach - static linking is better for whole-program optimization, dynamic linking allows updates, etc...but that's a topic for both an article and a thousand flame wars, outside the scope of your question.

To summarize quite simply: MingW is actually cheating, and the static library loads an external DLL. GCC on Linux is statically linking all the way through.

Comment: The question is about a library size, not an executable one.

Answer (score 1):

Try running strip against your Linux library. This will remove the debug information.

```
$ strip libpcre.a
```